# How to know if my computer supports a triple monitor configuration?

Tags: kde, manjaro, multi-monitor, display-settings, display-manager

I'm currently ruining manjaro KDE and trying to setup three monitors. my laptop has an HDMI output and a VGA one and I would like to use both to setup two additional screens but I seem to be able to use only one at a time. If I try to enable the other one disables automaticaly. Does my computer not support a triple monitor configuration? Am I doing something wrong? How can I know?

Comment: What video card/GPU does your computer have?

Comment: it's a laptop. It runs an integrated intel's graphics card.